# Postman returns "Could not get any response" on Laravel backend - XAMPP on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, laravel, postman

So I'm running a Laravel backend for my app, and for the last year Postman has been working like a charm, suddenly a couple of days ago it just stopped working.

I updated the app and nothing changed. It's the standalone app, not the Chrome browser extension. I turned off the SSL verification in the settings pane, but still no changes.

Any API request through Postman only doesn't return anything, works fine in the actual website in Chrome.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you ping the domain or ip in a terminal?

Comment: I also see you've been having page load issues in another question. Might be a good idea to try a vagrant box and get away from your mucked up osx build.

Comment: @JaredEitnier I pinged it and it is received normally in less than a ms each time! And I tried looking into a vagrant box, but I don't seem to have enough SSD to support using one, and I have a couple deadlines coming up, however I'd definitely look into it in the future!

Comment: You might need to try to do your requests in terminal then. Possibly Postman is trying to use some proxy to hit your requests. I don't know enough about it unfortunately. If you don't have enough SSD space left (this happened to me too) - you can actually run vagrant boxes completely off a flash drive. I did this on a fast USB 3.0 drive and it was awesome.

Comment: That's actually awesome to hear! I have a pretty big USB 3.0 external HDD, so that should be perfect. I don't know much about virtual machines though so it will take some time to understand how it all works. Any good resources you'd recommend? @JaredEitnier

Comment: Installing Virtualbox is super straightforward. https://www.vagrantup.com documentation is also really good on it's own. When I went to make the switch of moving to external I just [used this search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=moving+vagrant+to+external+drive&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). Probably best to install default way first and follow the guides on how to switch to external. That coupled with the [Homestead docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) it's pretty much a breeze. Laracasts.com are also very useful for specific issues.